# Ring Buffer - Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I want to make an application that stores (since opened) the last 2 or 3 seconds from the current moment (until is closed).
Is it possible with any of this methods?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBufferSource

Comment: PS: *store in a Blob

Comment: PS1: Here is the deal:
- Save the last milliseconds;
- Quantify the energy of the voice (micro) in real time;
- Save the last milliseconds + the voice above a limit of energy;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not by themselves.  But you can do this with some clever restructuring of RecorderJS - https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs.

Comment: Here is the deal:
- Save the last milliseconds;
- Quantify the energy of the voice (micro) in real time;
- Save the last milliseconds + the voice above a limit of energy;

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with a [WebAudio DelayLine node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DelayNode).
Without knowing what you want to do with the audio, it's hard to say if this solves your problem, but variants on this (creating AudioDestinationNodes and feeding a ring buffer in JS, etc) should handle any variation.

Comment: Here is the deal:
- Save the last milliseconds (of voice);
- Quantify the energy of the voice (micro) in real time;
- Save the last milliseconds + the voice above a limit of energy;
[Some kind of minimalist VAD]